# How to display 2 digits after dot in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, number-formatting, numeric

I have a table which their values are **`NUMERIC(16,4)`**

Example:

```
12.4568
13.2
14.05
```

I want to display the value with only 2 digits after dot without rounding.
Expected result is:

```
12.45
13.2
14.05
```

What I did is:

```
Select price::Numeric(16,2)
from prices
```

It works however I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it. I think it's better to use some kind of display edit rather then casting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can do this in following way:

```
select round(cast(your_float_column as decimal(10,2)), 2, 1)
from your_table
```

If you just want to skip round off then

```
select round(12333.347, 2, 1)
```

hope this will work for you

Comment: What the third argument "1" is for? With it, I got an error.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try:

`Select round(price,2)
from prices`

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
select price::decimal(16,2) from prices
```

Comment: This answer was flagged for review as [Low Quality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality) and could benefit from an explanation. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not good answers** and are likely to be downvoted as **not useful**. Explain what it does and how it's different / better than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29770932)

Answer (score 0):

Trunc worked well in similar case.

```
trunc(42.4382, 2)
42.43
```

The documentation:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-math.html